# Can Custom Tabs, Names, Labels translations be exported?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench

I've added Spanish names for our custom objects in Rename Tabs and Labels.  I have then exported the metadata translations from Setup -> User Interface -> Translation Workbench -> Export.  The resulting file has all our other translations -- custom fields, custom labels, page layout sections, etc.  But the translations for the custom object name, name field label, and tab name are not in the exported file.

Anyone know if export/import supports these items and if there's a way to get it to work?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.workbench_export_data.htm&type=5

Comment: I have read the doc on Translation Workbench.  

I have Translation Workbench working and have exported all the translations in the org.  The translations for Rename Tabs and Labels aren't in the file. 

One challenge with the SF documentation is it often not document when something is not implemented.  Hence my question about whether there is something I can do to get the translations for Renamed Tabs and Labels for custom objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious, but that's only for some of the metadata (e.g. custom fields, custom objects, etc). Standard values that are translated by Rename Tabs and Labels is found in the [Translations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_translations.htm) Metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this gets translation info.  That might be enough and it will be easier to use the metadata directly instead of using the export/import....

```
    <types>
        <members>MyObject__c-es</members>
        <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>es</members>
        <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
```